# Generate PDF from div

Tags: reactjs, jspdf

I am using jsPDF:

```
import jsPDF from "jspdf";

const noop = () => {};
  
  const elementRef = React.createRef();

  const savePDF = () => {
    const doc = new jsPDF({
      orientation: "p",
      unit: "pt",
      format: "letter"
    });
    const element = elementRef.current;
    const margins = {
      left: 40,
      top: 40,
      bottom: 40
    };
    const options = {
      width: 500
    };
    doc.fromHTML(element, margins.left, margins.top, options, noop, margins);
    doc.save("hmw.pdf");
  };
```

And within the return:

```
<button onClick={savePDF}>Generate PDF</button>
<div ref={elementRef}>12345</div>
```

However, all I get back on the console is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: doc.fromHTML is not a function
```

If I remove that line, the PDF is created but it comes back blank.

How do I correct this?

Answer (score 0):

The fromHTML function was replaced by html in 2.0.0.

You can read more about in their issue [here](https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF/issues/2992)

Comment: Thank you ... it now downloads the PDF, but the PDF is still blank?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like maybe the method you want is [doc.html](http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-html.html)

Answer (score -1):

you can use like below code:-

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#btnPrint").live("click", function () {
                var divContents = $("#dvContainer").html();
                var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=400,width=800');
                printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>DIV Contents</title>');
                printWindow.document.write('</head><body >');
                printWindow.document.write(divContents);
                printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
                printWindow.document.close();
                printWindow.print();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1">
        <div id="dvContainer">
            This content needs to be printed.
        </div>
        <input type="button" value="Print Div Contents" id="btnPrint" />
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```